# Comparing numbers from File and PrintWriter

Tags: java

I have to write a function using PrintWriter which compares line by line:
int in calkowite.txt with sredniaCalk and if int is bigger -> print it in cpowyzej.txt
double in rzeczywiste.txt with sredniaRzecz and if double is bigger -> print it in rpowyzej.txt

Why doesn't it work?

```
String buf;
 File rpowyzej = new File("c:/folder/rpowyzej.txt");
 File cpowyzej = new File("c:/folder/cpowyzej.txt");
 File rzeczywiste = new File("c:/folder/rzeczywiste.txt");
 File calkowite = new File("c:/folder/calkowite.txt");
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(rpowyzej);
 PrintWriter cpw = new PrintWriter(cpowyzej);
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(calkowite);
 Scanner sr = new Scanner(rzeczywiste);
 double sredniaRzecz = 0.28340862342710715;
 int sredniaCalk = 1;

 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     if (Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) > sredniaCalk){
         cpw.println(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
     }

 }

 while (sr.hasNextLine()) {
         if (Double.parseDouble(sr.nextLine()) > sredniaRzecz) 
             pw.println(Double.parseDouble(sr.nextLine()));

     }

 pw.close();
 sc.close();
 sr.close();
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at pliki1.Pliki1.main(Pliki1.java:82)

Comment: You're calling "sc.nextLine()" twice in each loop.

Comment: you should throw a try/catch around the parseInt and parseDouble function calls

Answer (score 1):

Only read the line once per pass through the loop:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    if (i > sredniaCalk){
         cpw.println(i);
    }
}
```